# Insert current date into ASP SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

have a table with a transaction date in it. It is set as a timestamp and basically I want on creation of a new record that field automatically inserts the current date.  I am using visual studio 2010 and ASP.net SQL not sure how to go about it. Dont need SQL injection protection for this just a simple way of doing it. Any ideas?

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Oracle has a SYSDATE() function,
- SqlServer has GETDATE()
- MySQL has NOW()

Use it in your DML (SELECT, INSERT) statements

Comment: Hi I put in GETDATE() and it says does not exist in the current context.

Comment: <strike>Is this on Oracle? If so 'SELECT SYSDATE() FROM DUAL;' should work</strike> (I see you added proper tags now); also see [here](http://www.grantondata.com/community/dbrosettastone.html) **Extending answer for MySQL**

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[ErrorLog]
           ([ErrorTime]
           ,[UserName]
           ,[ErrorNumber]
           ,[ErrorMessage]
)
     VALUES
           (GetDate() --This will work for MSSQL
           ,'userName'
           ,7551
           ,'I inserted the current date/Time'
)
```

or (again for SQL server)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ErrorLog ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_ErrorLog_ErrorTime_current_DateTime DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR ErrorTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is in a stored procedure, then getDate() should work.  If it is a sql command string that you are sending via ado.net, then you need to do this (example in VB):

sqlString="Insert into myTable (myDateTimeColumn) Values ('" & now() & "')"

myCommand.Execute(sqlString) ... etc.

Comment: GetDate() will work just from the client side (ie ado.net command).  There really is no difference from running the above statement from SSMS or from a ado.net command.  The only difference you will see is the database's current dateTime or the client's.